# Why do we use combinations for determining # of heads in n coins tosses?

Tags: combinatorics

I was taught that combinations gives us the number of unique sets irrespective of order, e.g. a,b and b,a are counted as one entry (see below for an example from wiki). I was wondering how this concept is connected to tossing 2 of heads in say 4 tosses of a coin. If we represent this as unordered sets we have only one set {H,H,T,T}. [image] The answer for 2 H in 4 tosses is 4C2 but how do we connect these two ideas?

Comment: Thats because H and H are indistinguishable, so position 1,3 and 3,1 are the same, you should account for that

Answer (score 1):

For you example ${H,H,T,T}$ you have a total of $4!$ possibilities to arrange them. But $H$ and $T$ are twice in your set, and you could interchange them without changing the arrangement. For $H$ you have $2!$ possibilities for interchanging them and for $T$ you have $2!$ possibilities also. Hence we have to correct $4!$ by dividing by $2!2!$. This gives $\frac{4!}{2!2!}=$${4}\choose{2}$.

Comment: I understand, but I'm just having trouble understanding the connection between arrangements and unordered set counting.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that rather than tossing the coins, we place them on the table, arranging them in each possible order so that two heads and two tails are showing.  The possible arrangements are:

HHTT, HTHT, HTTH, TTHH, THTH, THHT

Note that in each case, an arrangement is determined by selecting which two of the four places will be occupied by coins showing heads.  Thus, the number of ways in which two of the four coin tosses result in heads is the number of ways we can select two places from four places, which is $\binom{4}{2}$.

More generally, the number of ways $k$ heads and $n - k$ tails can appear in $n$ tosses is equivalent to the number of ways we can arrange $k$ heads and $n - k$ tails on a table, which is determined by which $k$ of the $n$ places will be occupied by heads.  The number of ways we can do this is $\binom{n}{k}$.